# Finding a thin conductive, non-magnetic material

Tags: electromagnetic

I want to find the thinnest possible material, so it lets through most of the 30 kHz magnetic field, but is also good for use as a terminal for an "air" capacitor. The material should have the highest as possible permitivity so that the capacitance is as big as possible and as low as possible magnetic permeability so that the eddy losses are small as possible because of reduced skin effect.

I need a material sheet or spray to then make as small as possible layer (order of one micron). What material to use and where to actually get it. It would be best to be easily obtainable. This is going to be used in the end in mass production so the focus should be on price as well. But for now it's just for predevelopment.

Comment: The dielectric material between the plates determines the capacitance.

Comment: A conductive material won't have a high permittivity.

Comment: Explain the best material you have found so far in your research and link to tables of data that you have found useful. Otherwise it looks like you are looking for a free design service (which this is not).

Comment: @Transistor also, a free material research … this doesn't sound like usual materia at all.

Comment: Also this smells a lot like an XY problem.

Comment: Heh, @PlasmaHH, you beat me at stating that observation. 
OP: and if you're doing this for mass production, you'll need someone who really knows these materials' properties very well. I'm afraid that's completely out of scope for free internet answers, and more like long-term consulting, or letting someone with experience at building speciality devices actually build your device.

Comment: Unwind a tubular metalised polypropylene high voltage capacitor, almost all types use metalised plastic foil as the combined dielectric and electrode. You can assume that the metalisation is as thin as you are going to find commercially available anywhere, and it has the plus of being on a thick strong plastic carrier. Then experiment with it to see whether it's adequate. Depending on the size you want, that might be usable as your source. If not, it will point you at the sort of place to get it made.

Comment: Thank you Neil_UK. This is really helpfull and just what I was looking for. I just wanted a quick answer from someone who knows a bit about these materials so I don't wander in the dark for too long before finding a good solution. :) How about carbon spray?

Comment: Eddy currents are due to induced voltages circulating a current and are made worse by low permeability materials.

Comment: Oh, because material is much thinner than skin depth, it doesn't matter much if we reduce skin effect. But permeability itself reduces eddy currents? :) Didn't think of it like that. Thanks!

Comment: But doesn't permeability just make eddy currents spread in a wider area? Which is not a problem in my case, because they would be induced in the whole part of my concuctor anyways no matter the permeability? Just the current density would get reduced and with it we would get less Joule losses. And more magnetic field would get trough because of it?